# Maven dependency for AbstractHandler

Tags: wso2

I'm trying to write a custom Authentication handler for WSO2 API Manager but I have a problem loading the correct classes for this.
Is there a Maven dependency that I can add to my pom, and the corresponding repository obviously, in order to get all the necessary dependencies?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define synapse and api gateway dependencies as follows. But note that the versions depend on the respective product version. To check the correct version of the dependency, check your `<product>/repository/component/plugins` and track the relevant jar.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.synapse</groupId>
        <artifactId>synapse-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2-wso2v4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

The repo can be

```
    <repository>
        <id>wso2-maven2-repository</id>
        <name>WSO2 Maven2 Repository</name>
        <url>http://dist.wso2.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>wso2.releases</id>
        <name>WSO2 internal Repository</name>
       <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
     </repository>

     <repository>
        <id>wso2-nexus-repository</id>
        <name>WSO2 nexus Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/</url>
    </repository>
```

Comment: Thanks Rajeev. I've updated my Nexus configuration to use the repository you mentioned and changed my pom to use the dependencies above but it gets stuck at org.apache.synapse:synapse-core:jar:2.1.2-wso2v4 with the error 
Could not find artifact org.apache.synapse:synapse-core:jar:2.1.2-wso2v4
What should be the versions needed for WSO2 API Manager 1.9.0?
Is there a jar or set of jars in the WSO2 API Manager 1.9.0 distribution that I should use for this instead of going through the WSO2 repository?

Comment: all dependency jars are there in <API Manager>/repository/components/plugins directory. You can find the version numbers there. When giving the error message 'could not find artifact', what's the repo in the error message that maven is connecting to?

Comment: Thanks Rajeev. I haven't tried the last repo you've added but the only thing I had to do was to add the synapse-core version 2.1.2 as a separate module in my local repository. I've taken the synapse jar from the plugins directory. For some reason maven wasn't able to locate synapse-core jar in any of the repositories I've tried, bar the latest one you've mentioned.